# Inserting 2 different rows from a select

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have this query that returns a list of customers that exist in one table, but don't in the other. 
For each of the returned customer_id, I need to add 2 rows into the profile table.

How would I write in sql the insert for the 2 rows?

```
select * FROM
(select * 
from customer c 
left outer join profile cp 
on cp.customer_id=c.global_id 
order by c.global_id) as A
where id is NULL;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to create a `cartesian product` using a `cross join`:

```
insert into profile (customerid ...)
select customerid ... 
FROM
   (select * 
   from customer c 
       left outer join profile cp 
           on cp.customer_id=c.global_id 
   ) as A cross join (SELECT 1 col UNION SELECT 2) as B
where id is NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

A `CROSS JOIN` (same as `,` in the `FROM` list) to a **[`VALUES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-values.html)** expression is the shortest and simplest way for a small number of rows:

```
INSERT INTO profile (<list of columns>)
SELECT <list of columns>
FROM  (
   SELECT <list of columns>
   FROM   customer c 
   LEFT   JOIN profile p ON p.customer_id = c.global_id 
   WHERE  p.customer_id IS NULL
   ) A
, (VALUES (1), (2)) dummy(col_name)
ORDER  BY global_id;
```

Use an explicit column list in `SELECT` and `INSERT` to avoid unexpected results when you change anything later.

You are probably not going to `INSERT` two *identical* rows. You could provide useful values in the subquery `dummy` right away. Possibly with explicit type cast. Like:

```
(VALUES ('foo'::text), ('bar')) dummy(col_name)
```